# How to block duplicate process?

Tags: go

I have been working on a workaround so that if a container is started and meanwhile a duplicate container is started, so it should not proceed to run rather blocked until first container get exited successfully. To achieve this i used [flock](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Flock) but this certainly is not helping me, it works sometimes, i.e, One container aquire flock while another get blocked on it but sometimes both aquire flock and proceed to run. My use case is other container should wait until other container get exited successfully. Here is the code i'm using:

```
// Flock locks the jiva.lock file. If the file does not exist, it is                                                                                   
// created. If a new process is trying to access the same file it will                                                                                 
// return an error "resource temporarily unavailable".                                                                                                 
func Flock(dir string) error {                                                                                                                         
     logrus.Info("Take flock on jiva.lock file")                                                                                                        
     file, err := os.OpenFile(dir+"/jiva.lock", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR, 0644)                                                                            
     if err != nil {                                                                                                                                    
        return err                                                                                                                                     
     }
     // golang.org/x/sys/unix                                                                                                                                                 
     err = unix.Flock(int(file.Fd()), unix.LOCK_EX|unix.LOCK_NB)                                                                                        
     if err != nil {                                                                                                                                    
        file.Close()                                                                                                                                   
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed to flock, error: %v", err)                                                                                           
     }                                                                                                                                                  
     logrus.Infof("flock successful on file: %v", file.Name())                                                                                          
     return nil                                                                                                                                         
}
```

I'm using bind mount so that the file `jiva.lock` is get shared bw two containers. This is not working even if i'm running the binaries directly on my system and in docker container most of the time in both cases.I also tried to debug it with strace but it also shows that both have acquired flock successfully. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you mounting the directory, or just the individual file, as a volume?

Comment: i'm mounting the directory. It is not only happening with docker container but also happening with the simple binary also. I can also help with strace if you want.

Comment: Sounds like you can eliminate docker and kubernetes from the question tags since the problem is unrelated to that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I added with the thought that if others having same use case, they may find this kind of issues but i've removed it as per your suggestion.

Comment: You really need a distributed locking solution here - Consul, etcd, Zookeeper, Redis, looks like Kubernetes may have something built-in, and I see this embedded distributed locking option (though I haven't tried it) https://blog.minio.io/minio-dsync-a-distributed-locking-and-syncing-package-for-go-ca2c72dcc359

Comment: I think a distributed locking solution is quite some overkill here. A simple NFS share and a lock does it and is at hand more often than not. Even quite enterprisy software like Karaf uses this mechanism. What I find strange is that it works for me: https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/a84afb5e85c31932b3a6b4a4378d3ab5

Comment: Hmm, could it be that you are on Windows? Because I tested on Mac and Linux...

Comment: thank you all for your responses. I'm running it on Linux, my simple program works as expected but when i add the above code to my application code things start behaving mysteriously.